# javascript EventSource to update import progress in a php-file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, event-sourcing

I'm trying to implement a progress bar for importing records into a database.

The import is started using jQuery's $.post(...) sent to a php script on the server.

I tried several approaches:

- start the import and write the progress to a SESSION-Var, polling the var with a second call via EventSource

php for import is something like:

```
foreach($importProduct as $ip){
    $_SESSION['importedProducts'] += 1;
    // ... do the import-stuff
}
```

And then fetch the import-progress using EventSource

```
var jsonStream = new EventSource('eventSource.php');

    if(typeof(EventSource) === "undefined"){
        alert('browser doesn\'t support EventSource');
    }else{
        console.log('fetching stream');
        jsonStream.onmessage = function (e) {
            console.log('stream: ' + e.data);
            $('#eventReturn').html(e.data);
           //var message = JSON.parse(e.data);
          // handle message
        };
    }
```

and in the PHP-script

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

while(1){

    echo 'data: {"imported":"'.$_SESSION['importedProducts'].'","total":"'.$_SESSION['totalProductsToImport'].'"}';
    echo "\n\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
```

Which obviously doesn't work since the SESSION is not updated in between calls.

Writing the progress to a file and then read it out every second seems to be a bit of an overhead...

Another thing I tried is using a js-function that calls itself every second and attempts to get the progress from the same script - but it hangs until the import-script has finished

```
function uploadProgress(){

    // Fetch the latest data

    $.get('progress.php', function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });

    setTimeout(uploadProgress, 5000);
}
```

Any ideas?

Notes: I'm starting the Session at ever call (session_start). I'm aware that the «while(1)» creates an endless loop... :)

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution.

The trick was to open and close the session in between calls.

So in the import-script:

```
foreach($importProduct as $ip){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['importedProducts'] += 1;
    session_write_close();
    // ... do the import-stuff
}
```

and in the progress-script:

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

while(1){
    session_start();
    echo 'data: {"imported":"'.$_SESSION['importedProducts'].'","total":"'.$_SESSION['totalProductsToImport'].'"}';
    echo "\n\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    session_write_close();
    sleep(1);
}
```

Now the session gets updated continuously and I can use the EventSource-approach